# Data Validation from list but excluding value

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file that is a calendar with some specifications.
In some of the cells, in each day, I want to be able to choose two different names from the same list.
But I want the second cell to exclude the other cell's value from the drop-down list.
How can I do that?

Comment: You will need to have a dynamic list on another page to which the data validation references.  This dynamic list will remove the values as they are used.  It cannot be done inside the data validation.

Comment: @Scott Craner I don't think I can use that solution. It would need 6 different lists just for one of the days. Thank you anyway

Comment: So what was your solution? I'm also looking for a data validation list that selects from a column of data, but excludes any values that have previously been used.... Code example/screenshot would be great!!!

Comment: @ElasticThoughts I did not find a solution exactly as I wanted. I added a validation checking if the same name was selected on both cells.